# React Native 0.63 iOS 14 error on podfile

Tags: ios, react-native, glog

Recently I have updated a app for react-native 0.63 and this action have been caused some errors:
In the "pod install" an error appear:

```
Installing glog (0.3.5)
[!] /bin/bash -c 

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h

/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk
checking whether the C compiler works... no
/Users/anderzilla/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-40a13/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/anderzilla/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-40a13/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/anderzilla/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-40a13':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I tried "pod deintegrate", remove podfile.lock and others solutions to update libraries but nothing have worked yet.

I'm using last vession of xcode 12.2, big sur and node 12.

henp and thanks.